# How to retrieve array in Word2Vec

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, word2vec

I am trying to retrieve the array/vector of a word in my trained word2vec model.  In SpaCy this is possible with model.vocab.get_vector("word"), but I can't find a way to do it in word2Vec

Comment: You should edit the question to include the specific language tag. Do you intend the solution in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [gensim documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html):
Initialize a model with e.g.:

```
from gensim.test.utils import common_texts, get_tmpfile
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
    
path = get_tmpfile("word2vec.model")
    
model = Word2Vec(common_texts, size=100, window=5, min_count=1, workers=4)
model.save("word2vec.model")
```

Now, you can get word vector of for example `word` by:

```
model.wv['word']  # numpy vector of a word (OR: model.word_vec("word"))
```

Comment: Note there's no need to create a `path` variable that's never used; and while saving the model will work, it's not essential to later steps like accessing individual word-vectors.